# Is there a way to specify a 'any' route in global before routes for Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my current progress of my Vue App, I have successfully hid the navigation bar to guest users with the use of Vuex, but i still have a problem because i can still navigate them if i manually type the URL.

I have searched codes/tutorials in the internet but some of them are confusing or i dont understand at all since im still new to this. So, I tried and make my own code inside the global before guard.

Here's my code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {  
  var auth = localStorage.getItem("UserToken")
  if (auth !== null && to.path === '/') {
    next(false)
  }else if(auth === null && to.path === '*'){
    next('/')
  }
  else {
    next()
  }
})
```

the first condition is successful, logged in users cant go back to the login page.

the second condition doesn't have any errors but the guests can still navigate my pages

Comment: If you want any path then why not just omit the `to.path` portion of the condition altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Which routes do you want guest users to have access to? The `/` route (homepage), I'm assuming?

You'll need to change your second `if` condition to:

```js
else if (auth === null && to.path !== '/')
```

Meaning *if user is a guest **and** they are attempting to navigate to a non-homepage route*.

Rather than matching against paths, which may include dynamic parameters, I find it better to match against route names which are constant. You can give each route a name like this:

```
{
  name: 'home',
  path: '/',
  component: ...
}
```

then you can match against route names instead to make it more descriptive:

```js
else if (auth === null && to.name !== 'home')
```

Comment: Is there a way for it that it will apply to all of my routes dynamically? rather than inputting all of my route names inside the 'if statements'?

Comment: This concept is raised a lot on stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665090/734040) is an answer I wrote before which explains how to do this by tagging certain routes as requiring the user to be logged in to access.